# JavaFX Linechart Color differences

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Line Graph in JavaFx with two Lines and I want to color the Space between the  Lines. I Searched the Internet but did not find anything.
This is what i have:
[image]

And I want it to look like[image]:

Comment: To me it seems to be a custom LineChart impl where you override the `layoutPlotChildren()`. In that method you need to do a little math, maybe [this](http://www.frustfrei-lernen.de/mathematik/fleache-zwischen-funktionen.html) (in german) is helpful to you. The space between could be a svg path.

Comment: If the 2 series do not intersect, you may try to use AreaChart where the lower series has a transparent background.

Comment: @UlukBiy Normally this should never happen :-) Systole and Diastole are upper and lower blood pressure, so if they ever intersect, this chart will be the least problem... But in an AreaChart isn't the upper background painted down below to the axis too?

Comment: I ovrride the `layoutPlotChildren()` and it  works now Thanks so much

Comment: @NwDx ah yes you're right :)

Comment: @Zion Cool! Good to hear that you've solved it on your own.

Comment: @Zion If you want, you could post your solution as an answer below (and after some delay you will be able to mark it as correct). This will likely be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to a Comment from [NwDx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4170073/nwdx)
I was able to solve my Problem.

I overrited the `layoutPlotChildren()` of `Chart` like this :

```
 super.layoutPlotChildren();
    XYChart.Series s =  (XYChart.Series) getData().get(0);
    XYChart.Series d = (XYChart.Series) getData().get(1);
    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<X,Y>> systole = s.getData();
    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<X,Y>> diastole = d.getData();

    for(int i = 0; i < systole.size()-1; i++)
    {       
            XYChart.Data SysPoint  = systole.get(i);
            XYChart.Data DiasPoint = diastole.get(i);
            double x = getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(SysPoint.getXValue().toString()); 
            double y = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(DiasPoint.getYValue()); 
            double x2 = getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(systole.get((i+1)).getXValue().toString());
            double y2 = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(diastole.get((i+1)).getYValue());
              Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
              LinearGradient linearGrad = new LinearGradient(
            0,   // start X 
            0,   // start Y
            0,   // end X
            1, // end Y
            true, // proportional
            CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, // cycle colors
            // stops
            new Stop(0.1f, Color.rgb(255, 0, 0, .3)),
            new Stop(0.5f, Color.rgb(127, 0, 127, .3)),
            new Stop(1.0f, Color.rgb(0, 0, 255, .3)));

                polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                    x,y,
                    x, getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(SysPoint.getYValue()),   
                      x2,getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(systole.get((i+1)).getYValue()), 
                    x2,y2
                });
            getPlotChildren().add(polygon);
            polygon.toFront();
            polygon.setFill(linearGrad);
    }               


}
```

I create a Polygon wich connects two Systole and two Diastole Points and fill them with a LinearGradient.

My Chart now looks like:
[image]

Comment: Wow with a gradient! Really a nice solution, thank you for posting!