# Conditionally Color Background JavaFX LineChart

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm looking to conditionally change the background color of a line chart.  In the given example, I'm looking to modify the chart so that any sections with a Y value >=3 get shaded red in the background:

LineChartJavaFXTest.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LineChartJavaFXTest extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Seconds");
        yAxis.setLabel("Volume");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Test Chart");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        //populating the series with data
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 0));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 1));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 2));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 2));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 1));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 2));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 3));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 3));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 4));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 3));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 2));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 1));

        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("LineChart.css");
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
        lineChart.applyCss();

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

LineChart.css

```
.chart {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
    -fx-background-color: #010101;
    -fx-legend-visible: false;
}

.chart-content {
    -fx-padding: 30px;    
}

.chart-title {
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-font-size: 1.6em;
}

.axis-label {
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
}

.chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}

.chart-vertical-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke:#505050;
}

.chart-horizontal-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: #505050;
}

.chart-alternative-row-fill {
    -fx-fill:transparent;
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
}

.default-color0.chart-series-line {
    -fx-stroke: #0000ff;
}

.default-color0.chart-line-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: #0000ff, white;
}
```

Result
[image: Chart]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is inspired by the solution to [JavaFX Linechart Color differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601082/javafx-linechart-color-differences). I would advice you to go through it first.

This answer includes a single red color gradient because that is what OP wants.

**Solution**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LineChartJavaFXTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Seconds");
        yAxis.setLabel("Volume");


        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        //populating the series with data

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 0));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 1));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 2));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 2));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 1));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 2));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 3));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 3));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 4));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 3));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 2));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 1));


        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = 
             new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis, FXCollections.observableArrayList(series)) {
            @Override
            protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
                super.layoutPlotChildren();
                Series series =  (Series) getData().get(0);
                ObservableList<Data<Number,Number>> listOfData = series.getData();

                for(int i = 0; i < listOfData.size()-1; i++) {
                    // Check for Y value >=3
                    if(listOfData.get(i).getYValue().doubleValue() >= 3 &&
                            listOfData.get(i+1).getYValue().doubleValue() >= 3) {
                        double x1 = getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(listOfData.get(i).getXValue());
                        double y1 = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(0);
                        double x2 = getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(listOfData.get((i + 1)).getXValue());
                        double y2 = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(0);
                        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
                        LinearGradient linearGrad = new LinearGradient( 0, 0, 0, 1,
                                true, // proportional
                                CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, // cycle colors
                                new Stop(0.1f, Color.rgb(255, 0, 0, .3)));

                        polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                                x1,y1,
                                x1, getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(listOfData.get(i).getYValue()),
                                x2,getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(listOfData.get((i+1)).getYValue()),
                                x2,y2
                        });
                        getPlotChildren().add(polygon);
                        polygon.toFront();
                        polygon.setFill(linearGrad);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        lineChart.setTitle("Test Chart");

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("LineChart.css");
        lineChart.applyCss();

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Answered the question perfectly (overriding layout plot children is what I wanted).  Didn't see this other question when I posted mine.  Thanks.

Comment: I see strange rendering artifacts when I resize the window.

Comment: @Holger Please, post a new question.

Comment: But my comment just relates to the provided solution to this question. See https://i.imgur.com/ydIlI3J.png for an example screenshot